# Get all linearlayout child elements

Tags: android, android-layout

I have layout:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
  android:id="@+id/exchangeView">
 
     <TextView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="#fff000"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="Sticker 1"
         android:textColor="#372c24"
         android:textSize="20dp" />
 
  <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:gravity="bottom"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:id="@+id/next">
   
   <Button
   android:id="@+id/btn_next"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:text="Next" />

  </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and related code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.exchange);


    layout = (View) findViewById(R.id.exchangeView);
}
```

next thing I want to do is to get all children elements in this layout with `Id=exchangeView`, but when I type `layout.getChildCount()` android studio IDE compiler says:

> Cannot resolve method 'getChildCount()'

However, if I put breakpoint on line where I assign `layout` a value, then if I evaluate expression I can execute method `layout.getChildCount()`

[image]

All I want to do is to execute `layout.getChildCount()` during runtime.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
layout = (View) findViewById(R.id.exchangeView);
```

to

```
layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.exchangeView);
```

I am assuming you have declared the variable layout as

```
View layout;
```

If so, change that to

```
LinearLayout layout;
```

The View class doesn't have the method getChildCount(), it is a method in the ViewGroup class. LinearLayout extends ViewGroup, and hence has access to it. View does not. This is related to polymorphism, which I suggest you look up.
Cheers.

Comment: Yeap, that was the reason of my issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

**You can try to use getChildCount() and also getChildAt() like this may be**

```
int childcount = ll.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
  View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
LinearLayout layout = setupLayout();
int count = layout.getChildCount();
View v = null;
for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    v = layout.getChildAt(i);
    //do something with your child element
}
```